# I have an .ova file that won't open in VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ovf, ova

When I try to import an .ova file in VirtualBox 5.1.8 I get an error:

```
Error reading OVA '/filename.ova' (VERR_TAR_UNEXPECTED_EOS).


Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
```

I've seen some info that I might need to update VirtualBox or maybe the .ova file is corrupt. I'm hoping it's something else. I don't want to update VirtualBox and the .ova file was quite large and I don't want to download it again. Any other possibilities of what this error might be suggesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer in my case turned out to be that an .ova file is basically an .ovf file in tar format, as summarized in a comment by [Chris TD](http://info.tatedavies.com/)  on a post: [OVA’s and OVF’s: What are they, and what’s the difference?](https://damiankarlson.com/2010/11/01/ovas-and-ovfs-what-are-they-and-whats-the-difference/)

So I just did

```
$ tar -xvf filename.ova
```

to get `filename.ovf` which I am able to import in VirtualBox.